# How do I make the Azure backup work with Terraform?

Tags: azure, automation, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I am trying to have backup initiated for Azure VM with terraform but it is not taking the source_vm_id parameter. I have it listed as below

```
#https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/backup_protected_vm.html
resource "azurerm_backup_protected_vm" "BackupProtected_app_vm_01" {
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name}"
  recovery_vault_name = "z1-r-op-rsv-01"
  #source_vm_id        = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.app_vm_01[count.index].id}"
  source_vm_id       = [element(azurerm_virtual_machine.app_vm_01.*.id, count.index)]
  backup_policy_id    = "${azurerm_backup_policy_vm.BackupPolicy_app_vm_01.id}"
}
```

I am getting the following error:
Error: Reference to "count" in non-counted context

on AGC.tf line 264, in resource "azurerm_backup_protected_vm" "BackupProtected_app_vm_01":
 264:   source_vm_id       = [element(azurerm_virtual_machine.app_vm_01.*.id, count.index)]

The "count" object can be used only in "resource" and "data" blocks, and only
when the "count" argument is set.

I tried to change it without using "element"  but it is still throwing out error.

Here is what I have for VM defined:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "app_vm_01" {
  count                            = var.app_vm_01_count
  name                             = "${var.reg}${var.dash}${var.env}${var.dash}${var.app}${var.dash}${var.app_vm_01}${var.dash}${format("%02d", count.index+1)}"
  location                         = var.location
  resource_group_name              = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  network_interface_ids            = [element(azurerm_network_interface.app_vm_01.*.id, count.index)]
  availability_set_id              = azurerm_availability_set.app_vm_01.id
  vm_size                          = "Standard_D2s_v3"
  license_type                     = "Windows_Server"
  delete_os_disk_on_termination    = true
  delete_data_disks_on_termination = true

  boot_diagnostics {
    enabled     = "true"
    storage_uri = var.dia_uri
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it without the brackets

```
source_vm_id        = element(azurerm_virtual_machine.vm.*.id, count.index)
```